# Echo the value of a field in a json file using batch script

Tags: json, batch-file, field

```
{
    "fields" : {
        "field_10061" : 24,   
        "field_10101" : "GB"
    }
}
```

I have this .json file named storage.json located in C:\files\storage.json and the contents of storage.json is as above:-

I want to create a batch file that stores the value of "field_10101" which is "GB" in a variable and echo it.
I have tried this command below but its not working.

```
set LOC=C:\files\storage.json

for /f  delims^=^"^ tokens^=3 %%A in ('findstr /R "field_10101" %LOC%') do set new=%%A

echo %new%.
```

Comment: With a doublequote delimiter, the third token is a sequence of space colon space on the target line.

Comment: I am pretty new to this, can you please enlighten me about the correct use of delimiter and tokens and what should I use for this particular case?

Comment: Clearly you want the fourth token if using a doublequote as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you so much. In scripting, I am not even a beginner(less than that). Can you please recommend me any/some good tutorials(paid/unpaid) to learn batch script and even VB script(I wanna learn that too).

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with JSON, so please use a proper JSON-parser!

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('
  xidel -s "C:\files\storage.json" -e "$json/fields/field_10101"
') DO SET "new=%%A"
```

Or with `--output-format=cmd` and the dot-notation instead of the XPath-notation:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('
  xidel -s "C:\files\storage.json" -e "new:=($json).fields.field_10101" --output-format^=cmd
') DO %%A
```

Or with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('
  jq -r ".fields.field_10101" "C:\files\storage.json"
') DO SET "new=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set LOC=C:\files\storage.json
for /f  delims^=^"^ tokens^=3 %%A in ('findstr /R "field_10101" %LOC%') do set new=%%A
call :getvalue %new%
echo %value%
goto exit
:getvalue
set "value=%~3"
goto exit
:exit
```

maybay use real json parsers? (as universal method that work with any json files)

```
vbs/wsh/jscript (native)             //maybay dll files?
powershell (native)                  //maybay in -Command "" and ignore Get-ExecutionPolicy ?
base64-encoded "internal components" //echo BASE64STRING... >tofile... ... certutil (native)
```